# Under what conditions does $f(z)$ continuous imply $\arg(f(z))$ continuous?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, continuity

My question is as stated in the title. Just to restate:

> Under what conditions does $f(z)$ continuous imply $\arg(f(z))$ continuous?

Attempt:

I propose that if for all $z$ in the domain of $f$, $ \operatorname{Re}(f(z)) >0 $, then $f$ continuous implies $\arg(f(z))$ continuous...

Comment: Are you considering $\operatorname{arg}$ to be a single-valued function or a multivalued function; and in the first case, what branch cut are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If f is continuous and never zero, then a continuous log (hence continuous arg as that can be taken as the imaginary part of the log) exists in any simply connected domain where f is defined.

Comment: Under more stringent conditions on f, always never being zero, of course, you can dispense with simple connectedness - for example, if the image of f under any loop "doesn't go around zero" which is the case when $\operatorname{Re}(f(z)) >0$, but that's quite strong.

Comment: Thank you very much!